Chrome version competitivity issue
I have my driver factory page
After running my script I am having this issue
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
      org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 125.0.6422.113 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'

I have tried by update my selenium version and I want to make it work

This question is similar to: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

please upgrade selenium to latest version, this error should resolve
